# Convert cell array of cell arrays to matrix of matrices

Tags: matlab

I can convert a cell array of matrices to matrix:

```
>> C={[1,1]; [2,2]; [3,3]};
>> cell2mat(C)
ans =
     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
```

This is OK. But, I want to convert a cell array including other cell arrays to a matrix:

```
>> C={{1,1}; {2,2}; {3,3}};    
>> cell2mat(C)
Error using cell2mat (line 53)
Cannot support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.
```

So, desired output is:

```
>> mycell2mat({{1,1}; {2,2}; {3,3}})
ans =
     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
```

How to do this?

### Edit:

I want to do same thing for multidimensional ones also:

```
>> mycell2mat({{1,1;1,1}; {2,2;2,2}; {3,3;3,3}})
ans(:,:,1) =

     1     1
     1     1

ans(:,:,2) =

     2     2
     2     2

ans(:,:,3) =

     3     3
     3     3
```

Answer (score 10):

To be honest, I never liked `cell2mat` for being slow, so I've come up an alternative solution using [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b) instead!

#### Transform a cell array of vectors

This is fairly simple, just use the [colon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator and [concatenate all vectors vertically](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html):

```
C = {[1,1]; [2,2]; [3,3]};
A = vertcat(C{:})
```

and so we get:

```
A =
    1   1
    2   2
    3   3
```

#### Transform a cell array of cell arrays

This is a bit trickier. Since it's a cell array of cell arrays, we'll have to obtain a vector of all elements by a double use of the colon and [`horzcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html), and then [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) it into the desired matrix.

```
C = {{1,1}; {2,2}; {3,3}};
V = [size(C{1}), 1]; V(find(V == 1, 1)) = numel(C);
A = reshape([horzcat(C{:}){:}], V)
```

and so we get:

```
A =
    1   1
    2   2
    3   3
```

The manipulation of `V` makes sure that `A` is reshaped correctly without having to specify the output dimensions explicitly (unfortunately, I didn't find a one liner for this). This also works for multi-dimensional cell arrays as well:

```
C = {{1, 1; 1, 1}; {2, 2; 2, 2}; {3, 3; 3, 3}};
V = [size(C{1}), 1]; V(find(V == 1, 1)) = numel(C);
A = reshape([horzcat(C{:}){:}], V)

A(:,:,1) = 
    1   1
    1   1

A(:,:,2) =   
    2   2
    2   2

A(:,:,3) =    
    3   3
    3   3
```

#### P.S

I think the correct result for the last example should be a 6-by-2 matrix instead of a 2-by-2-by-3. However, that is not what you requested, so it's off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
cellOfCells = {{1,1}; {2,2}; {3,3}};
cell2mat(cellfun(@cell2mat, cellOfCells, 'UniformOutput', false))
```

Edit:

I agree that keeping it simple is an important, but so is having fun :)
So - here's a one-liner that should do the trick (and can be easily generalized for any size):

```
a = {{1,1;1,1}; {2,2;2,2}; {3,3;3,3}}
reshape(cell2mat(cellfun(@cell2mat,a, 'UniformOutput', false))', 2, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronnyle, this is working for one-dimensional cells like I give as example. But I need to do same thing for multidimensionals also. Can you improve your answer in this way?

Answer (score 3):

keep it simple

```
c = {{1,1;1,1}; {2,2;2,2}; {3,3;3,3}};
z = zeros([size(c{1}) size(c,1)]);

for i=1:size(c,1)
    z(:,:,i)=cell2mat(c{i});
end
```

gives

```
EDU>> z    
z(:,:,1) =

     1     1
     1     1

z(:,:,2) =

     2     2
     2     2    

z(:,:,3) =

     3     3
     3     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the question is a long time ago - but maybe my answer might help other readers or searchers.
I think the *best* solution is nearly the idea presented by **Eitan T** but it is possible to do that without reshaping. For me

```
C={{1,1;1,1};{2,2;2,2};{3,3;3,3}};
A=cell2mat(cat(3,C{:}))
```

does what was asked for - thus answers with

```
A(:,:,1) =
     1     1
     1     1
A(:,:,2) =
     2     2
     2     2
A(:,:,3) =
     3     3
     3     3
```

Hoping that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I just commented out the lines in cell2mat that return the error and everything work fine to me.

lines to comment out in cell2mat (51:53): (you can find them using dbstop if error)

if cisobj || ciscell
    error(message('MATLAB:cell2mat:UnsupportedCellContent'));
end

I don´t think it is a good idea to change matlab functions, and I am pretty shameful of my solution myself, but it works.