# MATLAB: Using textscan and converting cell array in matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv, cell, textscan

I have a large csv file (should be around 1 million lines) with option data with the following structure (content is altered):

```
secid, date, days, delta, impl_volatility, impl_strike, impl_premium, dispersion, cp_flag, ticker, index_flag, industry_group
100000, 02/05/1986, 60, -80, 0.270556, 74.2511, 5.2415, 0.021514, C, ASC, 0, 481
100000, 03/05/1986, 30, -40, 0.251556, 74.2571, 6.2415, 0.025524, P, ASC, 0, 481
```

I have successfully imported a test file using the following:

```
ftest = fopen('test.csv');
C = textscan(ftest,'%f %s %f %f %f %f %f %f %s %s %f %f','Headerlines',1,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(ftest);
```

However, C is a cell array and this makes it harder to handle the contents of the file in matlab. It would be easier to have it as a "regular" array (pardon me for not knowing the correct nomenclature, I just started working with matlab).

If I output C, I get:

```
Columns 1 through 6
[2x1 double]    {2x1 cell}    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]
Columns 7 through 12
[2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    {2x1 cell}    {2x1 cell}    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]
```

So inside the cell array which is C, there are arrays and cell arrays - arrays for numbers and cell arrays for strings. If I try to check element (1,2), I have to use C{1}(2) but if I want to check element (2,2) I have to use C{2}{2}. Ideally, I would like to access both as C(1,2) and C(2,2).
The question is, how do I do this?

I have searched for solutions and found cells2mat but it only works if all content is numeric (I think). I found this solution: [Convert cell array of cell arrays to matrix of matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540418/convert-cell-array-of-cell-arrays-to-matrix-of-matrices) but horzcat retrieves an error, which I believe may occurr due to the same problem.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: A cell array is an array that can store values of different types. Here you have a cell array that stores both columns of numbers and strings. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540418/convert-cell-array-of-cell-arrays-to-matrix-of-matrices) assumes that all you have is numerical values, so a cell array is indeed redundant, and it _can_ be converted into a matrix, which is much easier to manipulate. But what do you expect to get when you have strings involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have an array containing both numeric and character data, what you want is impossible (and trust me, it would be impractical, too).

Referencing individual numbers in a numeric array is different from referencing whole strings. There is simply no escaping that, nor should there be: you treat flowers differently from how you treat people (I sure hope so anyway).

In MATLAB, a string is an ordinary array, with the difference that each entry of the array does not represent a number, but a character. Referencing individual characters goes the same as referencing numbers in arrays:

```
>> a = 'my string'
>> a(4)
ans = 
s
>> a+0  % cast to double to show the "true character" of strings
ans =
    109   121    32   115   116   114   105   110   103
```

However, `textscan` assumes (rightfully so) that you don't want to do *that*, but rather you want to extract *whole strings* from the file. And whole strings should be referenced differently, to indicate that you mean whole strings and not individual characters.

I think you'll find it all a bit more intuitive if you split the results from `textscan` up into an ordinary numeric array and a cell array of strings, like so:

```
% load the data
ftest = fopen('test.csv');
C = textscan(ftest,...
    '%f %s %f %f %f %f %f %f %s %s %f %f',...     
    'collectoutput', true,...
    'Delimiter',',\n');
fclose(ftest);

% split into numeric and char arrays
numeric = [C{[1 3 5]}]
alpha   = [C{[2 4]}]
```

Referencing data in `numeric` then follows the same rules as any ordinary array, and referencing the strings in `alpha` then follows the normal cell-referencing rules (as in `alpha{2,1}` to get `'03/05/1986'`)

**EDIT** Based no your comments, you want to do the conversion like this:

```
% Read the data
fid = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
C = textscan(fid,...
    '%f %s %f %f %f %f %f %f %s %s %f %f',...
    'Headerlines', 1,...
    'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);

% Delete 10th element ('ASC')
C(10) = [];

% Mass-convert dates to datenums
C{2} = datenum(C{2}, 'dd/mm/yyyy');

% Map 'P' to 1 and 'C' to 2
map('PC') = [1 2];
C{9} = map([C{9}{:}]).';

% Convert whole array to numeric array
C = [C{:}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Rody. I understand the issue. I am considering transforming date and cp_flag in numbers and ignoring the ticker field. Can you advise me if this is an efficient way of doing so? 
`ftest = fopen('testfile2.csv');

C = textscan(ftest,'%f %s %f %f %f %f %f %f %s %s %f %f','Headerlines',1,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(ftest);
for i=1:size(C{9})
    C{2}{i} = datenum(C{2}{i}, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
    if C{9}{i} == 'P'
        C{9}{i} = 1;
    elseif C{9}{i} == 'C'
        C{9}{i} = 2;
    end
end
C{2} = cell2mat(C{2});
C{9} = cell2mat(C{9});
C = [C{[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12]}]`

Comment: @japa: While your approach is not wrong, I edited in a version that is shorter, faster, and more MATLABy :)

Comment: Thank you very much @Rody, it is very fast like this. It processes the 1052480 lines file in roughly 10 seconds. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue...I'd prefer to have a 2-D cell array for easy accessibility and utilizing the built-in matlab sorting functions.

Here is another solution that might work for you (this is how TMW does it in their auto-generated code in the import tool). It turns the numerical arrays into cell arrays so that you can concatenate them into a 2-D matrix.

```
C([1,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12]) = cellfun(@(x) num2cell(x), C([1,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12]),'UniformOutput', false);

C = [C{1:end}];
```