# Read string from txt file and use string for loop

Tags: matlab, loops

Trying to read a txt file, then to loop through all string of the txt file. Unfortunately not getting it to work.

```
fid = fopen(fullfile(source_dir, '1.txt'),'r')
read_current_item_cells = textscan(fid,'%s')
read_current_item = cell2mat(read_current_item_cells);

 for i=1:length(read_current_item)

 current_stock = read_current_item(i,1); 
 current_url = sprintf('http:/www.', current_item)
 .....
```

I basically try to convert the cell arrays to a matrix as textscan outputs cell arrays. However now I get the message

Error using cell2mat (line 53) Cannot support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: This is because your cell array (read_current_item_cells), contains cell arrays within it.

Comment: Can you give a sample text read from 1.txt

Comment: Sure, thez are basicallz stock symbols  APPL next line MSFT etc. Would it be necessarz to put in a delimiter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540418/convert-cell-array-of-cell-arrays-to-matrix-of-matrices This would help you to visualize your problem.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, i found that post before while searching for a solution, unfortunatey I was still not able to fix it

Comment: It is quite impossible to solve this unless we have a glimpse of the input text from 1.txt. Like if it is a cell array of objects or cell arrays or vectors

Comment: At the moment it contains only the following:
LAD
AAPL

Comment: check `read_current_item_cells{1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What can happen is that the data gets wrapped into a cell array of cell arrays, and to access the stored strings you need to index past the first array with

```
read_current_item_cells = read_current_item_cells{1};
```

Converting from `cell2mat` will not work if your strings are not equal in length, in which case you can use `strvcat`:

```
read_current_item = strvcat(read_current_item_cells{:});
```

Then you should be able to loop through the `char` array:

```
for ii=1:size(read_current_item,1)

 current_stock = read_current_item(ii,:); 
 current_url = sprintf('http:/www.', current_stock)
 .....
```

Comment: @PeterHummer Accepting answer would be good if u find it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

That is the normal behaviour of `textscan`. It returns a cell array where each element of it is another cell OR array (depending on the specifier) containing the values corresponding to each format specifier in the format string you have passed to the function. For example, if `1.txt` contains

```
appl 12
msft 23
```

running your code returns

```
>> read_current_item_cells
read_current_item_cells = 
    {4x1 cell}

>> read_current_item_cells{1}
ans = 
    'appl'
    '12'
    'msft'
    '23'
```

which itself is another cell array:

```
>> iscell(read_current_item_cells{1})
ans =
     1
```

and its elements can be accessed using

```
>> read_current_item_cells{1}{1}
ans =
appl
```

Now if you change the format from `'%s'` to `'%s %d'` you get

```
>> read_current_item_cells
read_current_item_cells = 
    {2x1 cell}    [2x1 int32]

>> read_current_item_cells{1}
ans = 
    'appl'
    'msft'

>> read_current_item_cells{2}
ans =
          12
          23
```

But the interesting part is that

```
>> iscell(read_current_item_cells{1})
ans =
     1

>> iscell(read_current_item_cells{2})
ans =
     0
```

That means the cell element corresponding to `%s` is turned into a cell array, while the one corresponding to `%d` is left as an array. Now since I do not know the exact format of the rows in your file, I guess you have one cell array with one element which in turn is another cell array containing all the elements in the table.